# Use third party code in C#

Tags: c#, .net-assembly

I would like to use the following code in my program  (http://sshnet.codeplex.com/)[SFTP](http://sshnet.codeplex.com/)

I downloaded it and put into the same folder where my C# project is. I aslo added code:

```
using Renci.SshNet;
using Renci.SshNet.Sftp;
```

Now I need to tell Visual Studio where to look for it. I tried "Add Reference", but what I downloaded contains only files with extension .cs no .dll.

What do I do next?

I read a couple of books about C# (By Troelsen and Michaelis), but all this assebly business is not clear to me.

Comment: there is probably a .csproj file in what you downloaded. You need to add that as a project to your solution, and then reference that project using add reference.

Answer (score 13):

Instead of downloading the source (the link entitled `SshSource`), try a *binary* link (either the 4.0 or 3.5, depending on what .NET CLR version you are targeting).

The *binary* links will provide dlls.  Then, you can use `Add Reference` to link the dll in your project.

Binary distributions are what 3rd-party projects make available for use.  These are usually versioned by the project and stabilized before large public release.  These distributions give you the most stable component to use.

The source distribution provides all the source files.  You can use/modify the source (depending on the license), however, this requires you to compile before use.

[NuGet](http://www.nuget.org/) is a great way to use and manage packages for .NET.  `SSH.NET` also has a [NuGet Package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SSH.NET/).  If you use NuGet, this would be the preferred way to consume the binary distribution.

Comment: This is absolutely nice. I seriously have to get handy with NuGet. Thanks for that great link! Solved the same problem for me. :)

Answer (score 3):

Compile the code in order to get an assembly (.dll/.exe file). Then use "Add Reference".
Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

The source contains a `.csproj`. Just add the project to your solution and then `Add Reference > Solution > Projects`

Comment: clcto, I tried your suggestion. Now once I compile my code, if need to move executable to a different machine, how do I do it.? I tried simply taking mycode.exe and running it on different machine, but got an error message "Could not load file or assembly Renci.SshNet"

Comment: @user1700890 you have to copy all the `.dll` files from the same directory/folder as `mycode.exe`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of downloading source code, you need a compiled dll assembly, which can be found on Downloads tab. Grab either 'SshNet 4.0 Binary' or 'SshNet 3.5 Binary' depending on .NET Framework version you're using.

All the other steps you mentioned are correct.

Answer (score 1):

I would use nuget to download and install this package within visual studio.  Looks like they have a package for it.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/SSH.NET/

If you are not familiar with NuGet it is a package management system for visual studio that will automatically download and install the references for you.  Check it out here:

https://www.nuget.org/